# Casting a class to a selfmade class

Tags: java, class, casting

I am just playing around a bit with java and tried implementing a small Dungeon game.

Ma current problem is that I have a class "Monster" and a class "Trap". Furthermore I have a class "Encounter" in which either a monster or a Trap is randomly chosen and returned to compare to the hero's stats.

I don't really have an Idea how to convert this Monster or the Trap into an encounter, so I can use it.

This is my current method for the encounter:

```
public Encounter generate(){
  Encounter encounter = new encounter();
  Trap trap1 = new Trap(random, trap1);
  Monster monster1 = new Monster(random, random);

  if (random > 5){
    encounter = (Encounter) Monster; (?) //this is where I need help
 .....
```

Well, I hope i explained the problem throughouly enough.. Thanks in advance for your help!

(I looked elsewhere but didnt find a slution, might not have looked hard enough though or simply not known a keywoard, please excuse that)

Comment: I think i might not have fully understood the concept of casting...

Comment: Read about interfaces

Comment: Oh, and random is just a random int, i didnt want to put unessecary code in there, wanted to fucus solely on my problem

Comment: Okay thanks for that keyword, i will dig into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a class Encounter which can either be a trap or a monster, the best thing would be that both trap and monster inherit from encounter (or implement an interface encounter), so they have some shared methods, then you can just cast them, but you can't cast them if they don't implement common interfaces or share a common superclass.

Comment: But I wouldn't be able to write code in the interface would I (or is that just in abstract classes?)

Comment: Oh, I just have to make it default, got it :D thanks

Comment: Just to point out, using inheritance this way is called the "is-a" design pattern. The alternative is the "has-a" pattern. For this problem, you'd have 3 classes, Encounter, TrapAttributes, and MonsterAttributes.  Encounter would optionally contain either kind of attributes. While "has-a" code looks less elegant, it tends to be easier to change without breaking assumptions. See for example http://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/inheritance-composition-relationship.php